# Authenticating Android User Using Node.js/Passport

Tags: java, android, node.js, passport.js, httpurlconnection

I have made a web app that uses PassportJS to authenticate users and now I want to make an Android app for the same project. To login a user, I made a POST request to the login route using HttpURLConnection but I don't know how to handle the redirect made in Passport and I am not able to get the req.user JSON.

**Route I am calling:**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/',
    failureRedirect : '/',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

**Passport login**

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash("message", "Email not found"));
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash("message", "Incorrect password"));
        }
        console.log("Logged in!")
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

**Android code calling route**

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
     String urlParameters = "email=someemail@gmail.com&password=somepassword";
     String request = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/login";
     URL url = new URL(request);
     con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

     con.setDoOutput( true );
     con.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
     con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );

     OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
     out.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
     out.flush();
     out.close();

     String cookie = con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
     con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/").openConnection();
     con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
     con.connect();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The code above prints out "Logged in!" in the terminal I am running localhost:3000 but I cannot get req.user and it always redirects to "/" as a non-logged in user. Any suggestions on how to get req.user and keep the user logged in on the Android app would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to authenticate and Android app, is to

1. Authenticate the user in the Android App with the Google Signin for Android. Link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start
2. The Google SignIn above will generate a google ID token. The google ID token should be sent to your server. The server can get user details using the this ID. You can read more on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

This part can however be implemented using the strategy passport-google-token.

Create a route and strategy to validate the token on your server, and call the API from android passing the access_token as a variable.

Hope this helps and saves you time.